# internet explorer 10 no response on checkbox oncheckedchanged

Tags: checkbox, internet-explorer-10

All my codes are just working fine in any browser like Chrome, Firefox, IE8 and IE9. However, it cant work in IE10, it is no any response when I click on the check box. The following is my html code:

```asp
<asp:CheckBox 
    ID="TermAcceptCheckBox" 
    runat="server" 
    visible="True" 
    oncheckedchanged="TermAcceptCheckBox_CheckedChanged" 
    AutoPostBack="true" />
```

here is the cs file code:

```csharp
protected void TermAcceptCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (TermAcceptCheckBox.Checked) {
        btnAccept.CssClass = "blue-button19";
        btnAccept.Focus();
        btnAccept.Enabled = true;
    } else {
        btnAccept.CssClass = "grey-button19";
        btnAccept.Enabled = false;
        btnReject.Focus();
    }
}
```

Anyone know what is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: do you use jquery, if yes then try with: `var isChecked = $('#checkboxId').attr('checked');`

Comment: Yes, I have done it using Jquery. Just because my Boss want 2 version, 1 version is Jquery, 1 version is this post back method. Actually my boss didnt request it to work in IE 10. I ask this question just for myself learning : )

Comment: did you try to set value="1" to checkbox? and then to check value instead of "checked" ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, it is same. no response. I put Response.Write("hit here") inside TermAcceptCheckBox_CheckedChanged(), also no response.

Comment: what about `onclick='...'` or `onchange='...'` instead of `oncheckedchanged='...'`?

Comment: Tried, it is same. And, if change to onclick or onchanged, it also wont work at Chrome and Firefox, if use oncheckchanged, at least it still work at Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If this is working in Internet Explorer 8 and 9, I would think this has something to do with the problems ASP.NET had in identifying Internet Explorer 10. Scott Hanselman blogged about this, and provided a couple solutions in [Bug and Fix: ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing `_doPostBack is undefined` JavaScript error](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx).